# How to preserve dynamically created Tailwind classes (JIT mode) from being purged?

Tags: laravel-blade, tailwind-css, jit

I want to build a color palette Blade component, but I noticed that dynamically created Tailwind class strings are not preserved in Tailwinds JIT mode (see [Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html)).

### Example

A minimal example of what I want to achieve would look something like this:

**/tailwind.config.js**

```
...
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: [
      './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],
    theme: {
        colors: {
            primary-400: '#3892e6',
        },
    },
};
```

**/routes/web.php**

```php
...
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome', ['color' => 'primary']);
});
...
```

**/resources/views/welcome.blade.php**

```html
...
<body class="antialiased min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
    <h1 class="text-4xl text-{{ $color }}-400">{{ $color }}</h1>
</body>
...
```

The documentations approach of dynamically selecting a complete class name would render the component useless:

```html
<div class="{{  error  ?  'text-red-600'  :  'text-green-600'  }}"></div>
```

The documentation mentions two features that might help: [Safelisting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#safelisting-specific-classes) and [Transforming content](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#transforming-content).

So one way would be transforming the Blade templates to HTML but I believe this is not possible. The other way I can think of, would be generating the Safelist dynamically from the theme object, but I have no clue how to start.

Does anybody have had to tackle this problem before, or can think of another approach?